# Grab a certain table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a radio button per row.

```
<table id="t1">
 <tr><td><input type="radio" onclick="grab_row()" value=1></td><td>Data1<td>Data11</td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="radio" onclick="grab_row()" value=2></td><td>Data2<td>Data22</td></tr></table>
```

I would like to have a function that grabs the values of the row selected via radio.

my function:

```
function grab_row () {
    var radio = $("input[name=t1]:checked").val();   
}
```

The function only grabs the radio id that is currently selected.

for example, if the first radio is clicked, Data1 and Data11 are returned.
Thanks

Comment: Radio button elements need name attributes.

Comment: First your markup is off (as @j08691 mentioned), aside from that once you select your radio button you can use [.parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) for example `$("input[name=t1]:checked").parent('tr')` to get the parent row.

Comment: Hello, when I alert i get [object Object], it seems as if its in there, how do i display the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my interpretation of what you're looking for

**html**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="myradio" />
    </td>
    <td>Data1</td>
    <td>Data11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" value="2" name="myradio" />
    </td>
    <td>Data2</td>
    <td>Data22</td>
    <td>Data222</td>
</tr>
```

**js**

```
$("input:radio[name=myradio]").click(function () {
var myvals = [];
var elem = $(this).parent().next();

while (elem.prop("tagName") == "TD") {
    myvals.push(parseInt(elem.html().substring(4)));
    elem = elem.next();
}
console.log(myvals);
});
```

I assumed that you just need the integers after the "Data" string, but you can grab the entire content of the TD element with just the .html() and leaving out the .substring(4)

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zv6PH/)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.val()` when using a selector that returns multiple elements, it will only return the value of the first element. Instead, you need to iterate through them using `.each()`.

```
var values = [];
$("input[name=t1]:checked").each(function(idx, val) {
   //spin through and collect each val
   values.push($(val).val());
})
console.log(values); //view values in console
```

Comment: when i alert values, it alerts the first element, what is "idx"?

Comment: `idx` is the index value passed in from the each loop. Check the [documentation on .each()](http://devdocs.io/jquery/each) for more details.

Comment: Don't use alerts. Use [console.log()](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)

Comment: Noob question, console on firebug? or in my function?

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because I see no console. thanks

Comment: Click the link I included in my second comment to learn how to use it - https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: thanks, i see the console in chrome but it only result is only giving me the first value still. I've used the code you suggested as well

Answer (score 0):

This should be your jQuery:

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

and this should be your HTML:

```
<table id="t1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="foo" value="2" />
        </td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data22</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EmyfU/)**

Note that you can also use `$("input[name=foo]")` instead of `$("input[type=radio]")`.

Comment: is there something i have to set up because I see no results, im using firefox btw. thanks

Comment: The Firebug extension would be helpful. Or use Chrome and open the dev tools with F12.

Comment: ahh ok cool, i see the console with the result but not all the data in the row, but thanks anyway